# iphone sdk: set focus to different tabbar view on button click from first tabbar item

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How can I set focus to different tabbar view on button click from first tabbar item? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution:

```
HelloWorldAppDelegate *theDelegate = (HelloWorldAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
tabController = theDelegate.tabBarController;
tabController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

U missed the Pointer

L1AppAppDelegate *theDelegate = (L1AppAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
    tabBarController = theDelegate.tabBarController;
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = YOURTABBARITEMController;
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController 
    = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Do NOT forget to declare `YOURTABBARController` in the interface (.h), synthesize it, and #import the interface file into your .m file.

Plus for me I `MYTABBARController` was declared as `@class` in the interface too.

You can get this to work for you.... and look like a KING!!!